# Directly connect Windows and Ubuntu computers via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, windows, ethernet, file-sharing

I have the following computers on a network:

- Lenovo B570e [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS]
- Dell Inspiron N4050 [Windows 8.0 Professional]
- HP l1000 [Windows 8.1 Enterprise]
- Compaq [Mercury, don't know the exact name] [Windows XP SP3]

I want to share data between PC's and i have Ethernet cable [simple, not crossover]

Desktop is 32Bits and all other machines are 64Bits.
I want to share data between Ubuntu and Windows.

How can i achieve this? 
I know FileZila and network methods but i want faster and Ethernet cable method due to large amount Data.

Comment: I assume there is a router between these computers to allow them to share an internet connection... But you want to connect them directly not through the router?

Comment: yeah ther's a router but i want it done via ethernet

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect my desktop and my laptop using an ethernet cable to transfer files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59906/how-do-i-connect-my-desktop-and-my-laptop-using-an-ethernet-cable-to-transfer-fi)

Comment: Yes, it's possible, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59906/). However, it is really not worth it, you won't see much (if any) speed difference. As Oli said, you will be limited by other things. I suggest you just use your router normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short of it is, unless you've got a really bad router, that's probably just as fast as anything else.

The following are the main bottlenecks exist in a network for file transfers in the order of most likely to be limiting you.

- Bad wireless chipsets (some Broadcom) are capped at low speeds like 72mbps so won't give you more than 9MB/s.
- 100mbps network hardware will limit things to a maximum of 12MB/s
- Average 300mbps wifi will stop you going faster than 37MB/s
- Slow hard disks (5400rpm laptop disks for example) will cap out at 40-70MB/s
- Faster 7200rpm disk are then there at about 110MB/s write
- Gigabit hardware and great wifi (802.11AC on dual band) will raise its head now at ~120MB/s
- Average SSDs will cap out at 100-200MB/s
- Good SSDs will cap out at 500-1000MB/s
- 10gbps ethernet will predictably limit you to ~1.2GB/s provided the hardware is good.

Even with a direct (no router, no switch) network, you're limited by your crappiest component. In the laptops, we're talking about cheap 100mbps ethernet adaptors and those energy efficient hard disks.

And while I'm talking about routers and switches, most of these can allow massive throughputs. Many cheaper gigabit routers will allow ~200+MB/s to flow through them. Routing is not an expensive procedure.

If you need to move something fast and often, you're probably going to need to overhaul a lot of hardware.

Comment: that's very useful information but still my answer isn't given ! tahnks anyhow!